# Autenticar Angular com a Steam

Tags: typescript, angular

Estou tentando autenticar meu app Angular com a Steam, porem esta gerando esse erro no log:

```
Failed to load http://steamcommunity.com/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

O erro ocorre ao construir o component, ao clicar em login, ele não gera nenhum erro, porem não é redirecionado para tela de login da Steam.

Meu código fonte:

```
  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
    this.oauthService.redirectUri = window.location.origin + '/index.html';
    this.oauthService.clientId = 'spa-demo';
    this.oauthService.scope = 'openid profile email voucher';
    this.oauthService.oidc = true;
    this.oauthService.setStorage(sessionStorage);
    this.oauthService.issuer = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
    this.oauthService.requireHttps = false;
    this.oauthService.dummyClientSecret = 'geheim';

    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument().then(() => {
      this.oauthService.tryLogin({});
    });
  }

  public login(): void {
    this.oauthService.clientId = 'spa-demo';
    this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
  }
```

Estou utilizando o Angular 5.

Documentação do provedor Steam OpenID:
https://steamcommunity.com/dev?l=portuguese

Answer (score 1):

Tenta desativar seu firewall, se não funcionar tenta rodar em outra máquina ou em uma hospedagem profissional.

Pode ser o Xampp ou Wamp também

Comment: Eu tentei desativar o firewall e rodar o app em uma hospedagem profissional, e o problema ainda persiste.